# Usar jQuery-Mask com Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Estou tentando utilizar o jQuery-mask com o Laravel, mas não funciona. Se alguém puder ajudar :)

Quando olho para a aba Console do Google Chrome ele da o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código está da seguinte forma (tag head):

```
<head>
<script src="/public/jquery-mask-plugin.js" defer></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7MY6EG5ass8JhTuxBek18r5YG6pllB9zLqE4vZyTn4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>N. S. de Fátima</title>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-VGP9aw4WtGH/uPAOseYxZ+Vz/vaTb1ehm1bwx92Fm8dTrE+3boLfF1SpAtB1z7HW" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/regular.css" integrity="sha384-ZlNfXjxAqKFWCwMwQFGhmMh3i89dWDnaFU2/VZg9CvsMGA7hXHQsPIqS+JIAmgEq" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/brands.css" integrity="sha384-rf1bqOAj3+pw6NqYrtaE1/4Se2NBwkIfeYbsFdtiR6TQz0acWiwJbv1IM/Nt/ite" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-1rquJLNOM3ijoueaaeS5m+McXPJCGdr5HcA03/VHXxcp2kX2sUrQDmFc3jR5i/C7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Página onde tem o input tentando usar a classe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
        $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
        $('.date_time').mask('00/00/0000 00:00:00');
        $('#cep').mask('00000-000');
        $('.phone').mask('0000-0000');
        $('.phone_with_ddd').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
        $('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
        $('.mixed').mask('AAA 000-S0S');
        $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
        $('.cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00', {reverse: true});
        $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
        $('.money2').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
        $('.ip_address').mask('0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ', {
            translation: {
                'Z': {
                    pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true
                }
            }
        });
        $('.ip_address').mask('099.099.099.099');
        $('.percent').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});
        $('.clear-if-not-match').mask("00/00/0000", {clearIfNotMatch: true});
        $('.placeholder').mask("00/00/0000", {placeholder: "__/__/____"});
        $('.fallback').mask("00r00r0000", {
            translation: {
                'r': {
                    pattern: /[\/]/,
                    fallback: '/'
                },
                placeholder: "__/__/____"
            }
        });
        $('.selectonfocus').mask("00/00/0000", {selectOnFocus: true});
    });
</script>
```

Input:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="cep">CEP</label>
     <input id="cep" type="text" class="form-control">
     @if($errors->get('cep'))
        <p class="text-danger">Corrija este campo.</p>
     @endif </div>
```

Comment: Tem que carregar o jQuery `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` antes dos plugins.

Comment: o erro continuou o mesmo :/

Comment: O *plugin* da máscara deve ser carregado após o *jquery* e sem os atributos `defer` ou `async`

Comment: sim, tentei desta forma também e não rolou. Não tenho mais ideias do que fazer hahah

Answer (score 0):

Troca essa linha:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

por

```
$(document).ready(function($){
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar a tag script dentro do body do seu código, no final. Se estiver usando o @hasSection para verificar se existe algum script, coloque antes.

Remova também o defer ficando assim:

Ex: 

...

@hasSection('script_exemplo')
    @yield('script_exemplo')
@endif

Answer (score 0):

Para funcionar você precisaria fazer essas alterações:

Alterar isso:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Para isso:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Escolher se vai usar o jqueryMask local ou remoto, e não usar os dois. E mover aquele que você escolher para baixo da linha do script jquery, ficando assim:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7MY6EG5ass8JhTuxBek18r5YG6pllB9zLqE4vZyTn4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Ou assim:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/public/jquery-mask-plugin.js"></script>
```

Outra coisa, eu sugeri remover a propriedade "defer" dos scripts, nesse caso o ideal é mover todos esses scripts para o final do HTML, deixando eles logo acima da tag < /BODY>:

```
  <script>...</script>
  <script>...</script>
  <script>...</script>
</body>
```

Ou então, adicionar a propriedade "defer" em todos os seus scripts, inclusive naquele que você definiu as masks... Eu prefiro mover tudo para o final, antes da tag body...

Answer (score -3):

Precisei usar essa a biblioteca jQuery-Mask-Plugin no Laravel, compartilho a minha solução.

Formulário Cadastrar

```php
 <!-- resources/views/user/create.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('script')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#cpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
   });
</script>
@endsection

@section('content')
<form class="form-group" action="{{ action('UserController@store', 0) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>CPF</label><br>
        <input class="form-control" id="cpf" type="text" name="cpf" required><br>
    </div>
</form>

@stop
```

```php
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
 <!-- resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
<body>
    <div id="app">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.js"
        integrity="sha256-yE5LLp5HSQ/z+hJeCqkz9hdjNkk1jaiGG0tDCraumnA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!-- Carrega o Script Personalizado na Página aqui -->
    @yield("script")

</body>
</html>
```